# Cannot send HTTP request Android

Tags: android, http, get, altbeacon

I have modified the RangingActivity of the [Albeacon Reference Application](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference) to send an HTTP request each time a change is detected with respect to the beacon. I just need to send a request to the server, and that's that. No further interaction required.

All works well till the HTTP request is made - where nothing happens:

```
@Override
public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
    beaconManager.setRangeNotifier(new RangeNotifier() {
        @Override
        public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            if (beacons.size() > 0) {
                Beacon firstBeacon = beacons.iterator().next();
                logToDisplay("The first beacon " + firstBeacon.toString() + " is about " + firstBeacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
                String distance = String.valueOf(firstBeacon.getDistance());
                String url_string = "http://" + IP_string + "/index.py?name=" + Name_string + "&location=" + beacons.iterator().next().getId2() + "," + beacons.iterator().next().getId3() + "&distance=" + beacons.iterator().next().getDistance();
                Log.v("url", url_string);

                try {URL url = new URL(url_string);
                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        conn.disconnect();
                    } catch (IOException e){Log.v("error", e.toString());}
                } catch (MalformedURLException m){Log.v("error", m.toString());}

                }
            }
        });

    try {
        beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(new Region("myRangingUniqueId", null, null, null));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {   }
}
```

I am new to Android, so I am not sure whether this is running on the UIThread. If it is, then I'll really appreciate some help in implementing this using Asynctasks (or any alternate method that might help my case).

Comment: Have you looked into using libraries to make HTTP requests? If not, maybe you should take a look at a few as they have done most of the heavy lifting for you. Try looking into Square's Retrofit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a step here:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.disconnect();
```

try that:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
int response = conn.getResponseCode();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "The response is: " + response);
is = conn.getInputStream();
conn.disconnect();
```

and finally read: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

Comment: Doh! Silly of me. Thanks for the help and reference. I always ended up on the documentation page where they guide you on how to connect to a website using Volley.